# curl codeblocks windows без .dll Это возможно?

Tags: c++, dll, codeblocks, setup, libcurl

Мне удалось запустить curl на Codeblocks под Windows.

Теперь у меня возник вопрос: »можно ли как-то писать программы без использования файла 'libcurl.dll'? (Я не очень люблю '.dll'-файлы.)«

И если да, то как это сделать?

Заранее извиняюсь за свой плохой русский, так как я не могу на нем говорить, но на английском 'StackOverflow' мало что есть для 'Codeblocks', так как используют 'VisualStudio'. Мои начальные проблемы с 'curl' я смог решить благодаря русской версии.

С наилучшими пожеланиями из Австрии.

Comment: Проблема не в среде программирования, а в используемом компиляторе. Насколько я помню, cUrl поставляется с исходными текстами, и возможностью скомпилировать из них статическую библиотеку.

Comment: Вот же есть вопрос про статическую линковку libcurl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68265857/using-static-libcurl-a-in-c-program-by-mingw64